# How can I pass variables from an HTML form to a Windows cmd file?

Tags: html, forms

I need to pass variable values from an HTML form to a Windows cmd file.  I've spent all day so far researching it but have found only how to pass the values to a PHP script.  Due to constraints imposed by my company's IT department I need to use a Windows cmd file.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<html> 
    <head> 

        ...

    </head> 
    <body>

        <form action="../cgi-bin/create_new_study_directory.cmd" method="Post"> 

            <table> 

                <tr>
                    <td>Name of new study:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name_of_new_study"><td> 
                </tr> 

                <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

                <tr> 
                    <td>Raw data directory:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="raw_data_directory"><td> 
                </tr> 

                <tr> 
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Create new study directory"></td> 
                </tr> 

            </table> 

        </form> 

    </body> 
</html>
```

and here is the cmd file:

```
@echo off
cls
@echo I received %*
```

When I put values into the HTML form and click on the Submit button, the cmd file executes, but it prints "I received" with no values in the "%*" array.  My understanding was that whatever program was identified in the action tag in the HTML form would automatically receive the values of the fields in the form as parameters, but my cmd file is not seeing them.  What do I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. A batch file isn't meant to receive input directly from an HTML form.

Comment: Forming any sort of execution chain between a web page and a command prompt is the very definition of A Bad Idea. Rethink your architecture.